# Nuget: Add file to consuming project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense, nuget

I would like to add an XSD file to a Nuget package. When a project installs the Nuget package, this file should be included in the project, in order to allow Intellisense in the project's app.config file.

I can add the XSD to the Nuget package just fine, but I don't know how to make it show up in the project that uses the dependency.

Can this be done?

FWIW There are some extra sections injected in the project's app.config file (via Nuget's ["transform" capability](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations#Configuration_File_Transformations)). The XSD offers Intellisense for those extra sections, and Visual Studio automatically picks up XSD schemas included in the project (or even solution) that match the declared namespace of the XML elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include an XSD file for a configuration section with a NuGet package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16528358/how-do-i-include-an-xsd-file-for-a-configuration-section-with-a-nuget-package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nuget has the option to run custom install Powershell scripts that get a reference to the project that is installing the package.

Details:
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Automatically_Running_PowerShell_Scripts_During_Package_Installation_and_Removal

Here are some usage examples:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/209522/PowerShell-Script-Examples-for-NuGet-Packages